# Why are google ads not displaying on the homepage of my Wordpress Site?

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress, adsense

so google ads are not displaying on the home page of my wordpress website, if I go to /home they will not display, however if i go to any other link in that wordpress site they show up fine (/home/category/example). I have the ads set to display in the right sidebar on every page and in the left and right footer of every page. But I honestly don't understand why the ads won't show up on ONLY the homepage.

If I view the source of the home page, save it to my computer as test.html, and open it, the ads display fine! I'm not sure what could be causing this. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the url to the home page:
(Link removed -- Question answered)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's a new site, I would give it some time before suspecting any errors. First of all, AdSense needs time to crawl the site. Secondly, and perhaps more importantly, the pages must have some content so AdSense can find keywords and show relevant ads. Even then, ads can't always be shown if AdSense doesn't have any relevant ads in store at the moment.

Browsing your site, ads sometimes showed up especially in the category listings and month archives. Sometimes all three slots, sometimes only one or two. And sometimes none.

[Here's a nice AdSense Help entry](http://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=10035) for you to read.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

They should show up within an hour. Google has a troubleshooter you can use here
http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10036

Comment: Are you sure? Have you read the question and the accepted answer?